# In Angular (using angularfire2 and typescript) how do you get types on errors thrown when using firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Angularfire2 makes it easy to use firestore. But I can't find any documentation on how to get typings for errors thrown?

For example you can delete a document with:

```
return this.itemsCollection.doc(idOfItem).delete();
```

This returns a promise. When/if it fails, how do I get types on the error code?

I imagine I have to cast is to something?

I tried to read the documenation on firebase.google.com, and think I have found the ref file here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code

But how do I cast the error so I get typings in typescript?

Comment: The docs you've linked in your question are the Android SDK Reference. I think [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreError) is what you wanted. All the error codes are strings.

Comment: Thanks for the link - it works! Now Im just trying to get the corresponding retry strategy to work in rxjs - but thats a subject for another time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out you can do it like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

this.itemsCollection.doc(idOfItem).delete()
.catch(err) => {
    const error = err as firebase.FirebaseError;
    // You can now check against errors from the documentation
    //  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreError
    if (error.code === 'permission-denied') {
       console.log('The user does not have access to this');
    }
}
```

The code is a string, so I don't know if there is a great advantage of the types, but well to answer my own question :)